# MSMQ private queue - not receiving

Tags: c#, msmq, console-application

New to MSMQ... My local queue never receives my test message.  I have verified that Message Queuing and Message Queuing Triggers are running in my Services dialog (Vista Ultimate).  Thoughts?

```
class ConsoleApplication
{
    private const string Path = @".\private$\SomeQueue";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var queue = !MessageQueue.Exists(Path) 
         ? MessageQueue.Create(Path) 
         : new MessageQueue(Path) { Formatter = new BinaryMessageFormatter() };

        queue.ReceiveCompleted += queue_ReceiveCompleted;
        queue.BeginReceive();
        queue.Send("test message");
        Console.ReadLine();
        queue.Close();
    }

    static void queue_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, 
                                        ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Received message...");
        var queue = (MessageQueue)sender;
        try
        {
            var message = queue.EndReceive(e.AsyncResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Processing message...");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            queue.BeginReceive();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just had a thought, try deleting and re-creating the queue with MessageQueue.Delete(Path).  And it worked.  I guess my queue was hosed somehow.

Comment: Get new object reference to the sender object queue

var queue = (MessageQueue)sender;

and then using the same object for new BeginReceive(). huge mistake. It gives stack overflow exception please keep this in mind

Answer (score 2):

try adding

```
queue.ReceiveCompleted += queue_ReceiveCompleted;
```

in finally block of  `static void queue_ReceiveCompleted(object sender,  ReceiveCompletedEventArgs e)` event.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that the queue itself was broken.
More likely a timing issue between creating the queue and accessing it.
MSMQ has to perform various operations, such as create a config file in the LQS directory, before the private queue is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the console concurrently.  Try doing a thread.Sleep() and set a boolean in your callback.  Then you can do a readline after the boolean is set to read your output.

```
while (!received)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Perhaps you might want to use a breakpoint and the debug.WriteLine() to read output written into the visual studio output window.